# Sony SpresenseにおけるGNSSの精度について

Tags: spresense, gps

Sony SpresensのArduinoサンプル=gnss.inoを修正して、位置測定結果をSDcardに保存して、その緯度経度をQGISにプロットした結果、以下の様な状況で、思ったより位置精度が出ていないと感じていますが、この程度なのでしょうか？

＜改造点概要＞
1. QZSS_L1Sを使用する様に変更。
　　static enum ParamSat satType =  eSatGpsQz1cQz1S;
2. pdop>5以上はデータ取得しない。

＜測定場所状況＞
1. 広場にて、遮蔽物が無い場所で測定。
2. Spresensは、台の上に置いて連続測定を行う。

＜結果状況＞
1. 測定結果のpdopは殆ど２以下。
2. 位置計算に使用している衛星数は１０〜１２個
3. プロット結果は、以下の様な範囲に分布する
　　　緯度方向：　33.123245239〜33.123268127（差分：約0.082秒）
　　　経度方向：　131.810440063〜131.810516357（差分：約0.274秒）
4. 仮に１秒３０ｍとすると
    緯度方向：2.5m　の範囲に分布する
    経度方向：8.2m　の範囲に分布する
5. プロット結果を添付します。
 赤は同時にiPhoneXRで測定した位置です。
　緑はSpresensの位置です。数字はpdopの値です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

プロット図のデータ分布が等間隔で格子状に並んでいるように見えます。
これから察するに、緯度・経度の有効桁数が足りていなくて
精度が悪くなっているように見えているのではないでしょうか。
的外れでしたらすみません。